# Makefile.mak giving error

Tags: makefile

I have Makefile.mak file.
I am trying to run using **make** command.
Its giving error 
'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Please help me.

Comment: What do you see when you invoke `command -v make`?

Comment: Problem solved by invoking make -i Makefile.mak